# AngularJS / Server Side Hybrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, authentication

I am just getting my feet wet with Angular, and am still struggling to find the best (best for "my" situation) solution for dealing with auth and authz. In terms of auth, I have seen many different examples of how to accomplish this all with the angularjs app. However, even after seeing all of these solutions I am leaning towards breaking things out so that the login page is not part of the SPA. Instead, it would be served up a via server side rendering framework. In my case it would be asp.net mvc but that is irrelevant - the concept is the same regardless of the tech.

So, when the app is first accessed the SPA component would be protected and only after authentication would it be served to the client. I feel like if you are serving up the SPA before auth, it's not truly secure. It also removes some of the complexity from the SPA in terms of login views and logic, etc which I like.  In addition, I'm thinking I may even want to handle other non SPA related activities outside of the SPA. Right now I can only see a need for user/auth stuff but at least the door is left open if necessary.

Regarding authz, I really can't escape this in the SPA. Obviously the back end APIs will be secured, but for a better UX I still need some concept of roles in the SPA so I can check routes and also handle the visibility of UI components.

Is this approach one that others have used successfully? I'm interested in hearing any success stories, but also any arguments for why this might not be a good solution.  FYI - my background is server side development, with heavy duty security requirements. That background makes the whole SPA concept tricky to swallow ;)

Comment: I'm having similar situation and I've thought about approaching it like you have after researching a while. Please do share some code if you have some working solution. Thanks.

Comment: @AD.Net I don't - yet. I was hoping to get some feedback before I do that.

Comment: Thinking about exactly the same thing. I don't see why it would not work but am unsure in the same way as you are.